# Internal links in WebView

Tags: android

I want to find out when a user clicks an internal link in a url currently opened in webview. How can I do that?

Thanks,
Farha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `WebViewClient` for the `WebView` and the `onPageStarted()` method will be called when the page loading is started.

***Edit:***
To be more clear, this may be a sample code:

```
WebView wview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
WebViewClient wvClient = new WebViewClient();
wview.setWebViewClient(wvClient);
wvClient.onPageStarted(wview, wview.getUrl(), null);
```

Comment: Hey Karan, i tried again what u had mentioned and it worked.. :)

Thanks,
Farha

Comment: Can you post your solution..as i have same problem

Comment: Use webView.setWebViewClient() to set the WebViewClient and override the onPageStarted method of WebViewClient.